# taking time stamped sequence of images from a video using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

How should I take time stamped images from a video using ffmpeg?
for example;

```
image-0001 --> 0:00:00.0000
image-0002 --> 0:00:01.0000
image-0003 --> 0:00:02.0000
.....
```

I have tried;

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv -ss 00:00:00.0000 -r 1 image%4d.jpg
```

But it seems that using this code, ffmpeg does not take exactly one picture per second and the time of the taken pictures can not be calculated accurately from the image file number.

Comment: How comes it is a programming question?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.
But, I am trying to use ffmpeg+python for taking pictures from video.